# How to push all branches after clearing git file history

Tags: git, github

I have been following the instructions to remove sensitive information from my github repository using these instructions https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data . Everything is working correctly until I try to force push the changes to my repository.

According to the guide, I need to:

```
git push origin master --force
```

That worked and my master is updated. The guide now says,

> You will need to run this for every branch and tag that was changed.
>   The --all and --tags flags may help make that easier.

I was able to update all tags using:

```
git push origin master --force --tags
```

However, I am not able to update all of the remote branches. I have tried to run this command:

```
git push origin master --force --all
```

But I get this error:

> error: --all can't be combined with refspecs

I have also tried to push to the individual branches with this command:

```
git push origin dev --force
```

But I get this error message:

> error: src refspec dev does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:

How can I push to all of my remote branches to rewrite their history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
git push -f --all origin
```

The error "--all can't be combined with refspecs" occurs because you're specifying "--all" alongside the specific branch "master", and you have to pick one or the other. The error "src refspec dev does not match any" occurs because you apparently don't have a refspec called "dev", but you're trying to push it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work for me. The command succeeds , but says "Everything up-to-date". Checking in github shows the other branches do not have their histories revised.

Comment: @AaronWilliams: Hmm, I tested this locally and it worked, so I'm surprised. Have you tried a `git fetch origin` locally to see where the remote branches now are? GitHub itself can sometimes be slow to refresh.

Comment: @AaronWilliams: I'm assuming you have tracking branches for all the branches you're trying to push and that they've all been individually updated locally to remove the sensitive data. Is that correct?

Comment: I did not have any tracking branches. The guide seemed to suggest getting a new clone so I did not have any of my original branches. Once I added in the tracking branches everything seems to be updating properly. Thank you.